# When I "ctrl click and drag" in xcode interface builder, it says "File Owner" rather than my custom UIView

Tags: xcode, cocoa-touch, interface-builder

When I did it earlier with a UILable, the "referencingOutlet" was my custom UIView (called LocDebugView).

When I do it now, either with the original UILabel or a new one, it says "File's Owner".

When I try to run the code with "File's Owner", it crashes, saying "his class is not key value coding-compliant for the key npcsView.'"  or whatever I try to name the new variable.

What happened? What changed? How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I have no idea what changed, but I figured out how to fix it.  When I click and drag over onto the objective c class and I click the "object" drop down I can select the correct object rather than the apparent default of "File's Owner" which didn't work.